# Chrome CSS Styles doesn't work for dropdownlist if more than 300 items

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-chrome

I have a select box (dropdownlist) on my webApplication which can have atleast 1600 items. I have applied

```
{ font-size: 10px; font-family: Verdana; }
```

CSS styles to the dropdownlist. But, the style works only if the selectbox has less than 300 items. If the item count crosses 300, Option style becomes the browser default (i.e, Arial)

Comment: You seem to be correct. Here is the fiddle you could have made http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/1m8hsv9c/

Comment: Is there any workaround for this issue ?

Comment: Interesting question :)

Comment: I would raise a bug if it is not already known

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome developers didn't expect someone would put more than 300 items in a select dropdown so to improve performance they turned off css styling if you exceeded it. They are removing that restriction in v45. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513339

Comment: Thanks so much. I just updated my chrome to Version 45.0.2454.85 m, and it works :) 
Luckily, september 01 was the release date for v45 :))